# Mi dispositivo Android no se conecta con mi servicio web pero el emulador sí lo hace

Tags: webservice, android-volley, restful

Tengo un servicio web que se conecta a una base de datos *MySQL* sin problemas y tengo una aplicación que debe realizar una petición tipo *GET* y mostrarme los registros de dicha base de datos. Cuando ejecuto la aplicación en el emulador de *Android Studio* funciona a la perfeccion, mostrándome los registros de la base de datos pero cuando la ejecuto en mi celular no funciona y se ejecuta el método `onErrorResponse` del  `StringRequest` mostrándome un `Toast` con mensaje `null`.

Este es el `onCreate` de mi clase principal:

```
private String URL = "http://192.168.1.23:8084/ADProfesores/webapi/personas";

private ArrayList<Persona> personas = new ArrayList<>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2));

    final PersonaAdapter adapter = new PersonaAdapter(this,personas);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setMessage("Espere por favor...");
    dialog.show();

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    deserializarXML(response);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    if(dialog.isShowing()) dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error en la petición\n" + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(dialog.isShowing()) dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    queue.add(request);
}
```

Este es el método que deserializa los objetos `XML` del servicio web:

```
private void deserializarXML(String respuesta){

    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document xml = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(respuesta)));

        Element raiz = xml.getDocumentElement();

        NodeList listItem = raiz.getElementsByTagName("persona");

        for (int i = 0; i<listItem.getLength(); i++){
            Persona persona = new Persona();

            Node item = listItem.item(i);

            NodeList infoPersona = item.getChildNodes();

            for (int j = 0; j<infoPersona.getLength(); j++){
                Node dato = infoPersona.item(j);

                String etiqueta = dato.getNodeName();

                if(etiqueta.equals("identificacion")) persona.setIdentificacion(getValue(dato));
                if(etiqueta.equals("nombre")) persona.setNombre(getValue(dato));
                if(etiqueta.equals("apellidos")) persona.setApellidos(getValue(dato));
                if(etiqueta.equals("edad")) persona.setEdad(getValue(dato));
            }
            personas.add(persona);
        }
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error en la petición" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private String getValue(Node dato) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    String value = "";

    NodeList caracter = dato.getChildNodes();

    for(int i = 0; i<caracter.getLength(); i++){
        value += caracter.item(i).getNodeValue();
    }

    return new String(value.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8");
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que se genera en tu celular? ¿Qué es específicamente lo que no funciona?

Comment: esto pasa cuando no tienes un colector de error.

Answer (score 0):

hola primero que nada necesitamos depurar el codigo y saber de lado del S.O que esta pasando, te recomiendo usar un en tu codigo para que arroje posibles errores:

```
public void someMethod() throws IOException {
    try {
        //  Do database operation
    } catch (MyException e){
        throw new IOException(e.toString());
    }
}

//  Or, if there is no exception, use an unchecked exception:

public void otherMethod() {
    try {
        // DB operation
    } catch (MyException e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

para gestionar tus errores Lógicos. ten en consideración que algunos errores pueden ser por configuración de software(Firewall, puertos, etc)estaré actualizando este post e la medida que avances con el problema.

Comment: Gracias, ya me dí cuenta que era por el firewall

Comment: @jpromero que bueno entonces puedes escoger la respuesta que mas te ayuda o se acerca. saludos